# ¿Cuántos registros de cada hijo, tiene mi tabla padre?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo 3 tablas en MYSQL:

```
TablaPadre
Tabla2 (hija de TablaPadre)
Tabla3 (hija de TablaPadre)
```

Quiero saber cuántos registros de `Tabla2` y de `Tabla3` están relacionados a `TablaPadre` en un solo registro, algo como:

```
TablaPadrePk | TablaPadrecampo2 | count(Tabla2.Pk) | count(Taba3.Pk)
--------------------------------------------------------------------
     242     |    valorCampo2   |        2         |     3
```

Si hago un `left join` (para que `TablaPadre` siempre se muestre, independientemente de que haya hijos) usando solo la `TablaPadre` y `Tabla2`, obtengo el resultado esperado (obtengo ése 2).
Pero cuando hago el mismo `left join` usando las 3 tablas, lo que obtengo es:

```
TablaPadrePk | TablaPadrecampo2 | count(Tabla2.Pk) | count(Taba3.Pk)
--------------------------------------------------------------------
     242     |    valorCampo2   |        6         |     6
```

No encuentro una solución (o mis conocimientos de SQL ya no dan para más). Aquí dejo mi Query completo (juicios es la TablaPadre):

```
SELECT ju.idJuicio, ju.numeroJuicio,   
       count(ad.idAdmiteDesecha_Juicio), ad.idAdmiteDesecha_Juicio, 
       count(om.idOficioMulta), om.idOficioMulta,
       ad.sala
       FROM juicios ju
       LEFT JOIN admitedesecha_juicios ad ON ju.idJuicio = ad.idJuicio
       LEFT JOIN oficiosmulta om ON ju.idJuicio = om.idJuicio
       WHERE ju.idJuicio = 242
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma sencilla, es usar subconsultas para obtener la cantidad de filas por `idJuicio` en cada tabla y luego mediante un `LEFT JOIN` relacionar ambos datos con `juicios`

```
SELECT ju.idJuicio, 
       ju.numeroJuicio,   
       ad.CantidadFilas,
       om.CantidadFilas
       FROM juicios ju
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT idJuicio, 
                         COUNT(1) AS CantidadFilas 
                         FROM admitedesecha_juicios 
                         GROUP BY idJuicio
            ) ad 
            ON ju.idJuicio = ad.idJuicio
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT idJuicio,
                         COUNT(1) AS CantidadFilas
                         FROM oficiosmulta
                         GROUP BY idJuicio
            ) om
            ON ju.idJuicio = om.idJuicio
       WHERE ju.idJuicio = 242
```

Comment: Funciona a la perfección! Muchas gracias por la ayuda, Patricio!